# Como depurar uma aplicação em C/C++ remotamente usando ECLIPSE, sistemas operacionais diferentes?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ssh, gdb, cortex-a

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C++ que roda uma placa NanoPI M3 com Linux especialmente compilado para meu propósito, e tem acontecido certos erros e comportamentos inesperados, gostaria de poder depurar a aplicação remotamente já que o NanoPI M3 ser um Cortex-A53 com 8 cores não quero sobrecarrega-lo com ferramentas e o tempo de compilação que é maior que meu desktop (naturalmente).

Eu uso o Eclipse em uma estação Windows 10 com MSys2 para codificar e envio o código via GIT para o NanoPI M3 onde compilo diretamente nele as vezes já que meu ambiente no destkop está com problemas para cross compiling para Cortex-A.

Mas gostaria de poder em alguns momentos depurar o código através do **Eclipse** remotamente.

**Como posso fazer isso, usando o Eclipse?**

As máquinas estão em redes diferentes mas tem visibilidade uma da outra sem problemas. Se preciso posso usar SSH inclusive com Tunelamento para X11 (o que quero evitar)

Eu até consigo conectar via GDB porém ocorrem problemas já o GDB windows usa i386 e o Linux ARM usa ISA ARMv8-A, já tive sucesso em usar o GDB carregando o binário.

Tentei usar o GDB em dois linux iguais, mas ainda assim estou tendo problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Consulte ***[esta documentação](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html#Remote-Debugging)***, acredito que ela vai te dar um norte. A depuração remota serve exatamente para este propósito.

O primeiro parágrafo já explica.

> *If you are trying to debug a program running on a machine that cannot run gdb in the usual way, it is often useful to use remote debugging. For example, you might use remote debugging on an operating system kernel, or on a small system which does not have a general purpose operating system powerful enough to run a full-featured debugger.*

Que sistema operacional usa o NanoPI M3? Linux embarcado? Se for pode instalar uma VM no teu Windows e rodar um Linux para servir de servidor do GDB.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86645)

Comment: Esta é a página oficial do gdb, acho muito pouco provável que ela vá ser alterada.

Comment: Olá @gfleck, talvez eu não tenha me expressado claramente na pergunta, talvez eu até parece um pouco preguiçoso em ler o manual. Mas realmente minha intenção era obter uma resposta mais direta a esta situação. Irei dedicar um tempo maior e mais especifico a releitura do manual e buscar melhorar a pergunta caso a dúvida continue.

Comment: Tranquilo @Delfino, [aqui](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Connecting.html#Connecting) tem a documentação mais específica de como fazer isso, poderia até colocar aqui na resposta mas seria um ctrl+c e ctrl+v, porque a documentação ja é bem sucinta.